# To find the number of $10$ digit numbers, where the sum of digits is divisible by $10$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

To find the number of $10$ digit numbers, where the sum of digits is divisible by $10$.

---

The sum of digits is divisible by $10$ implies the sum has to be a multiple of $10$.

Since the number is $10$ digited, the first term has to take values greater than $0$.

Some of the numbers are all ones, $11\cdots11, 12\cdots10, 13\cdots100$.

I am finding it difficult to count the number of such numbers.

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of $10$-digit positive integers whose digit sum is $10$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig no...that is the question.

Comment: No, the question asks you find the number of $10$-digit positive integers in which the sum of the digits is divisible by $10$, so the sum could be $10$ or $20$ or $30$ or $40$ or $50$ or $60$ or $70$ or $80$ or $90$.

Comment: Note that you can set the first $9$ digits however you like, then there is a unique choice for the units place.

Comment: So if the sum of first 9 digits is already divisible by 10 we put 0 in the last place, else adjust accordingly @lulu

Comment: Whatever the sum of the first $9$ digits is, there is a unique value for the units digit that makes the digit sum a multiple of $10$.  Indeed, if $d$ is the sum of the first $9$ digits, just use $-d\pmod {10}$.  That is, pick the unique representative for $-d\in \{0, 1, \cdots, 9\}$.

Comment: "...else adjust accordingly": exactly! So the number of such 10-digit numbers is...?

Comment: Something a bit like that is done for credit card numbers.  At the cost of one extra digit you get some protection against mistakes.  Not quite so simple though since your method protects against one mistake but not against a transposition which is common.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will try to give an answer from the comments above:

---

Since we have to choose a $10$ digit number the first position has $9$ choices, then from the second position to the last but one we have $10$ choices each.

Now we sum all these $9$ entries and choose the last digit such that the sum is divisible by $10$. We can always do it and the choice for the last position is unique.

Hence the total number of $10$ digit numbers, where the sum of digits is divisible by $10$ is $$9 \times 10^8.  $$